# Not fiting real resolution

Tags: android, css, eclipse, android-layout, resolution

I'm working with a board wich has android 2.3 as base SO. This board has connected an 7" screen and I¡m using this set to develop an app.

While developing this app on eclipse, I'm using RelativeLayouts. This app will only be for an especific screen size, so for the moment I don have the need to use diferent resolutions to fit other screen sizes.

The problem that I'm getting is that I have developed all this program using on eclipse a 7" screen base, but when runing the app on the board, the layout doesn't fit the screen. It makes the same effect as if you create a layout fitting a 7" screen with RelativeLayouts, and then you change this resolution to 5.4". The layout gets oversized and doesn't fit well the screen.

So, what would be the problem? As i said, the screen is 7" and I'm developing for 7". I don't know why happens this.

Comment: What screen-size and resolution does the board report to Android? As tablet support wasn't officially introduced until 3.0, any 7"+ screen prior to that might be problematic (see original Galaxy Tab 7"). Find and run jotabout's screeninfo and report back.

Comment: @323go 7" screen WVGA 800x480

Comment: And what density? Have you run screeninfo yet?

Comment: It's not a tablet, its a board with a LCD screen attached. The information above is what the manufacturer provides. How can i run the screeninfo that you say?

Comment: Just like any other app. Google "jotabout screeninfo" and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, the pixel density of your board is different from the pixel density of your emulator (on eclipse).

I am assuming you did not set a "fixed" size on your images and layouts, only selecting match_parent for width and height, right?

What is happening is that android is scaling (or not) its resources based on your screen pixel density, and that gives you the difference between the emulator and the board.

Screen size does not means equal screen pixel density, and that can cause you a lot of trouble if you do not manage this correctly providing different resources and qualifiers.

Comment: Yeah, I selected `match_parent`. First I used the `layout-sw600-land` folder to store the layouts, but I got throubles with this, it didn't recognize this folder, so I have the layouts in the `layout-land` folder

Comment: Well, that's the problem... You will have to deal correctly with Android resources matching to resolve this, their site have a extensive guide and tutorial about the behaviour of that system. If i responded the question, please click on accept =)